# Undefined control sequence. Argument of \addtocontents has an extra }. Paragraph ended before \addtocontents was complete. -- cant fix

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, texstudio

I was using this same latex document in windows(texstudio) and overleaf without any error. Now in ubuntu Texstudio, I got these three errors.

```
Undefined control sequence. {\blx@err@patch{\addtocontents}}
Argument of \addtocontents has an extra }. {\blx@err@patch{\addtocontents}}
Paragraph ended before \addtocontents was complete. {\blx@err@patch{\addtocontents}}
```

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,headsepline,captions=tableheading,toc=bibliography,openany,chapterprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox} \usepackage{interval} \usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{placeins} \usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{placeins} \usepackage{pdfpages} \usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{booktabs}

\input{settings/packages} \input{settings/hyphenations}
\input{settings/commands} \input{settings/colordef}
\input{settings/tikzdef} \input{settings/tikzexternalize}
\input{settings/theorems}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}  \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newtoggle{lang_eng} \settoggle{lang_eng}{true} \newtoggle{enable_svg}
\settoggle{enable_svg}{false}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
\ifodd\c@page\else  \hbox{}     \vspace*{\fill}     \begin{center}
        \begin{quote}           {\textit{This page intentionally left blank}}
        \end{quote}     \end{center}    \vspace{\fill}  \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi} \makeatother

\begin{document} \pagenumbering{alph} \pagestyle{empty} 
\let\chapterpagestyleorig\chapterpagestyle
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\newcommand{\SubItem}[1]{\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item[-] #1}

\input{content/titlepage_english} \maketitle
\input{content/dedication} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/acknowledgement} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/abstract} \cleardoublepage

\setcounter{page}{1} \pagestyle{headings}  \pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{\chapterpagestyleorig}

\tableofcontents \newpage

\input{content/nomenclature} \cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic} \pagestyle{headings} 

\input{content/chapter1_english} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/chapter2_english} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/chapter3_english} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/chapter4_english} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/chapter5_english} \cleardoublepage
\input{content/chapter6_english} \cleardoublepage

\printbibliography \cleardoublepage \listoffigures \cleardoublepage
\listoftables \cleardoublepage

\input{content/appendix}
\end{document}
```

I have already included the biblatex package in my document, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring. I suspect that it might be related to the \blx@err@patch command, but I couldn't find any information on it.

This is the receptive MWE for the above issue, with packages and components.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage[normal,small]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[chapter, ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[noprefix,intoc,english]{nomencl}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen,style=authoryear-comp,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,isbn=false,doi=false,dashed=false,backend=bibtex,maxnames=2,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}
\usepackage{settings/bibspacing}
\setlength{\bibspacing}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{comment}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,hidelinks,pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}
\ifpdf
\else
\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    This is the introduction section.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately, it's impossible to debug something we don't know the contents of. Can you please try and produce a minimal example reproducing the issue?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error but its not working otherwise. Not sure what other inputs do u need for understanding the problem. I assumed that the main tex file is enough for debugging.

Comment: your main file contains e.g. `\input{settings/packages}`, and that means that lot of your code is unknown. We even don't know how you actually load biblatex or where exactly the error occur.  Compare the log-file of the working and the non-working compilation, then you can perhaps get an idea which difference if source of the problem.

Comment: see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1205. Apart from this: clean up your package list. I doubt very much that you really need everyone or that you even know what they are doing. You are loading packages that are obsolete and various packages are loaded twice Such a preamble is asking for trouble.

Comment: Off-topic:  Do check your packages and eliminate duplicates.  At least `newclude` and `epstopdf` are there more than once.

Comment: If I try to run your example I get `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'chapter' defined.` (which makes sense, because the `article` document class has no `\chapter`s). Then I get `! LaTeX Error: File `settings/bibspacing.sty' not found.` (which makes sense, because you haven't shared the file `settings/bibspacing.sty` with us). Then I get `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \bibspacing ` (presumably because that macros is defined in `settings/bibspacing.sty`, which we don't have). I then get a couple of knock-on errors from that. But that's it ...

Comment: ... I do not get an error about `\blx@err@patch{\addtocontents}`. Please minimise your example as much as possible (remove packages that don't make a difference) and make the example as "compileable" as possible for us: Remove unrelated errors. Then please post the full `.log` file of the minimised example. It might be too long for the question, so upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/. Ulrike's hunch about https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1205 is our best bet at the moment and we could verify if it by checking your `biblatex` version

Comment: Issue solved after commenting out few lines from biblatex.sty as mentioned in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1205. Thanks @UlrikeFischer and everyone for the quick fix. I will also consider reworking on the packages files and learn to create a approachable MWE instead in future.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here or do we close as "solved by an update", since the problem no longer occurs with recent `biblatex` versions?

Comment: @moewe I would close it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was due to in incompatibility of an outdated version of `biblatex` with `newcludes`/`tag.sto` that has been resolved in current versions of `biblatex`. The problem therefore no longer occurs with an updated system.